# Is there any difference between these two ER designs?

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm new to database designing.

I'm trying to figure out the difference between the following two ER designs:

[image]

Assuming each record in parent tables (**State** and **City**) participates in 1:M relationship in both the ER designs, is there any functionality difference that could arise among them? Is there any situation where I might prefer one over another?

Comment: In the first case the City determines the State; in the second it doesn't. That's a significant difference and what matters is which of these designs more accurately describes the reality you are intending to model.

Comment: We can also determine the State from City using the Locality table.

Comment: No, that is not implied by the second diagram because two different localities could be assigned the same City_id but different State_Ids. In the first diagram that could never happen. Therefore City determines (i.e. *functionally determines*) State in the first case but not in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's a valid point. However, practically we don't store a different State_Id for two same City_Id in the Locality table. And if that's the case is there any other major difference between the two designs?

Comment: Then it appears that your first diagram is correct whereas your second one doesn't accurately show the intended business rule that City_Id->State_Id. If these are supposed to be relational database designs then your second diagram would also violate 3rd Normal Form (first diagram looks OK).

Comment: Thanks for your insight. :)

Comment: Corner case:  Texarkana is in Texas and Arkansas

Comment: Neil, good point. In many situations the second diagram may be the more useful and correct design. But if theScorpion is correct that the requirement is City_Id->State_Id then presumably Texarkana would have to be assigned to one state or the other but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case the City determines the State (City_Id->State_Id); in the second it doesn't. That's a significant difference and what matters is which of these designs more accurately describes the reality you are intending to model.

If City_Id->State_Id is correct and if these are supposed to be relational database designs then the Locality relation described by the second diagram would violate 3rd Normal Form (first diagram looks OK).